# WCF endpoint exception

Tags: wcf

I am just trying with various WCF(in .Net 3.0) scenarios.

I am using self hosting.

I am getting an exception as "Service 'MyServiceLibrary.NameDecorator' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element."

I have a config file as follows (which has an endpoint)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>

      <service name="Lijo.Samples.NameDecorator"
               behaviorConfiguration="WeatherServiceBehavior">

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8010/ServiceModelSamples/FreeServiceWorld"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Lijo.Samples.IElementaryService" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WeatherServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And a Host as

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace MySelfHostConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost myHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyServiceLibrary.NameDecorator));
            myHost.Open(); 
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


}
```

My Service is as follows

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace MyServiceLibrary
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Lijo.Samples")]
    public interface IElementaryService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        CompanyLogo GetLogo();
    }

    public class NameDecorator : IElementaryService
    {
        public CompanyLogo GetLogo()
        {

            CircleType cirlce = new CircleType();
            CompanyLogo logo = new CompanyLogo(cirlce);
            return logo;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public abstract class IShape 
    {
        public abstract string SelfExplain();

    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Circle")]
    public class CircleType : IShape 
    {
        public override string SelfExplain()
        {
            return "I am a Circle";
        }
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Triangle")]
    public class TriangleType : IShape
    {
        public override string SelfExplain()
        {
            return "I am a Triangle";
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(CircleType))]
    [KnownType(typeof(TriangleType))]
    public class CompanyLogo
    {
        private IShape m_shapeOfLogo;

        [DataMember]
        public IShape ShapeOfLogo
        {
            get
            {
                return m_shapeOfLogo;
            }
            set
            {
                m_shapeOfLogo = value;
            }
        }

        public CompanyLogo(IShape shape)
        {
            m_shapeOfLogo = shape;
        }
    }

}
```

Could you please help me to understand what I am missing here?

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're self-hosting in a console app - how is your config set up??

- Does your `MySelfHostConsoleApp` project have an `app.config` file?
- Do you have the `MySelfHostConsoleApp.exe.config` in the same directory as the `MySelfHostConsoleApp.exe` file?

The error message just really means the config cannot be found and thus cannot be interpreted and used.

**UPDATE:** the other option is that WCF cannot interpret the config if it's present.

Check this out:

- in your .NET code, your service class that implements the service is called `MyServiceLibrary.NameDecorator`
- however, in your config, you call your service:

  ```
  <service name="Lijo.Samples.NameDecorator"
  ```

That's not going to work! You're mixing up the .NET namespaces and the service namespaces here - and the name you need to put in your service-side config is the .NET fully qualified type name (including the .NET namespace - *not* the service namespace!).

Your service host will look for an entry `<service name="MyServiceLibrary.NameDecorator">` based on your code - but it won't find it.

So you need to make sure to sync those two things up - the fully qualified service class name (including namespace and all) **MUST** match the `name="...."` attribute in your `<service>` tag in your config.

Comment: Hi Marc, In the Hsot project the app.config is added and in the bin\Debug "MySelfHostConsoleApp.exe.config" is created. Still I am getting exception.

Comment: @Lijo: Updated my answer - try that.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I got a new learning. - The “Service name” in the app.config is the class name that implements the contract, with its namespace. It is not related to the namespace of the contract.